# Opencv how to ignore small parts on image

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I need a little help in Opencv, I´m a beginner and don´t know all functions yet.
I´m trying to do an OCR in my licence plate, it´s an Brazilian plate. So after some image processing like cvCvtColor,cvCanny,cvFindContours and cvDrawContours, I get images like this:

[image: Plate]

It´s a fake image, I mounted this image because I don´t want to publish my real plate on the web. On my real image, there is only black and white color I painted some parts on this example because I want ignore this parts. Red color it´s a city name, yellow color is a hyphen separator and green color is the hole to fix the plate on car. I need to know if there is a way to ignore this small parts and recognize only big parts, so after this filter i can do my OCR processing. Any help?

Comment: Segment, get bounding box of each segment, discard all that are too small, i.e. where width < mimial width of a letter and height < minimal height of a letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it helps you in other situations but in this situation you can remove small contours using [erosion](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) or simply using `contourArea` for calculating contour's area (and remove contour if it's area is too small).